# How to hard define in code a matrix Integer[][]

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Question is simple for an expert

```
Integer[][] res= new Integer[][] {.....hard code some values here on 2 dim...}
```

How to return here 2 rows and 3 cols like this

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int[][] res = {{1,2,3},
               {4,5,6}};
```

Comment: Good but didn't the question want a Integer rather than an int? There is a subtle difference....

Comment: @mikera: You could convert the int[] over to Integer[]

Answer (score 3):

This should work. (But I am no java expert).

```
Integer [][] ints = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
```